# Independence of Unions of Independent Events

Tags: probability, independence

(I looked at similar questions here on math.stackexchange.com and also employed some humble Google-fu, but couldn't find much about this exact matter.)
I've been attempting to show that given some natural $n$ a set $\{A_i\mid i \in \mathbb{N}\cap[1,n] \}$ of independent events (not just pairwise but mutually independent), and given some natural $m<n$, the sets:
$$
A = \bigcup_{i=1}^{m}
$$
$$
B = \bigcup_{i=m+1}^{n}
$$
are also independent.
I've been trying to do so using (strong) induction on $n$. However, I kept getting stuck: I've proved as a lemma that if $A,B,C$ are mutually independent events then so are $A, (B \cup C)$ and was hoping to use that in my step somehow, but it all gets messy: I tried defining events $A$ and $B$ as unions as described above, but separating one of the events in, say, $A$, which is WLOG of size $>1$ (because induction base can handle $n=2$ so in the induction step we assume for $n-1$ & have $n \geq 3$), so instead of $A$ I use $A'=\bigcup_{i=2}^{m}$, $A_1$, and $B$ as my events, such that the total events of the form $A_i$ in every pair of events is less than $n$ ($A'$ and $B$ have $n-1$; $A'$ and $A_1$ have $m$; $A_1$ and $B$ have $n-m+1$, which is less than $n$ because we assumed $|A|>1$ and so $m>1$).
This proves pairwise independence. However, I'm struggling, for some reason, with the independence of all three; that is struggling to show the following:
$$
P(A'\cap A_1\cap B)=P(A')P(A_1)P(B)
$$

Perhaps more importantly: I feel like I'm trying to prove something simple in a complicated way. Would really appreciate some pointers or an alternative approach to this proof. (Or... a counter-example? Could it be?!)

Comment: Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First observation:** In general, two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if their complements $A^c$ and $B^c$ are independent.

Because your $A^c$ and $B^c$ are intersections, they are easier to work with when the issue is independence.

**Second observation:** The definition of mutual independence is such that if $\{A_i\}$ are mutually independent, then so are $\{A_i^c\}$.